# How do Deaf Muslims interact while veiled?

Tags: fiqh

Signed languages depend not just on movements of the hands, but also on subtle facial cues. Direction of eye gaze, puffed cheeks, and mouth movements are all essential elements of a signed language. Given that, wearing a full facial veil (as is the practice of many Muslim women) can significantly affect how one is able to communicate.

For those Muslims who consider the veil to be obligatory, are there any special provisions which would allow deaf Muslim women to communicate effectively via sign language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

السلام عليكم

As per my knowledge Veil can be relaxed upon some conditions,

- Such as If you are being forced to not cover face (happened in some countries ),
- Same as a women can uncover her awra'h (body parts which are needed to be veiled) when facing a medical problem and needs to show to a male doctor (but Female doctor is recommended) one can open the face.
- Similarly on many other issues Islamic rulings are relaxed when facing difficulties.

**P.S:** I'm not a mufti or a knowledgeable Islamic scholar I'm just a student of knowledge.